# Wagtail 2.14.2 ModulNotFound error after running makemigrations

Tags: python, django, wagtail, modulenotfounderror

3rd try of wagtail

I did install it after having created a virtual environment named wag-env with virtualenv within the directory websites/wag/, not in the .virtualenv folder. Command was "virtualenv wag-env".

Did pip install wagtail

Then ran wagtail start ready_wag

I then ran python3 manage.py makemigrations and get this error messages "ModuleNotFound error wagtail.models". A check in the lib confirmed that there is a models folder at wagtail root level, but no models.py.

That's my third try since yesterday, first was with mkvirtualenv, had the same problem, second was with virtualenv, trying to integrate a finished django project, and now trying to start a project from scratch.

I ran a pip freeze --user, there's a wagtail installed globally. Should I get rid of it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: which django version you are using

Comment: Latest I think, 4.1.1

Comment: Django 4.1 isn't compatible with Wagtail 2.x ...

Comment: Didn't know. 4.0 would ?

Comment: I think Wagtail 2.x only takes Django 3.x ... if you install wagtail first, it should load the correct versions. Any reason you're going with 2.x? 3.03 might be a better place to start. 4.x has issues, might be better to wait on that one.

Comment: No specific reason. Just did a try after downgrading to 4.0 within my virtualenv, makemigrations and migrate works fine, just had a warning while running runserver that some modules were obsolete, but it work so far. Will check it further. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `venv` to create my environments, never had issue. Sounds like you have conflicting versions of Django to match your version of Wagtail.

Here are my old notes from learning Wagtail, the process I still generally use for every project:

1. Create project folder, open terminal session in that folder
2. In project folder, create virtual environment (`python -m venv .venv`)
3. Start virtual environment (`.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.bat` or `source .venv/bin/activate`)
4. Install Wagtail (`pip install wagtail==3.0.3`) <- adjust version as needed
5. Start new project in current directory (`wagtail start project .`)
6. Install wagtail requirements (`pip install -r requirements.txt`)
7. If using POSTGRES, follow the POSTGRES setup instructions **BEFORE** migrating.
8. Provision database (`python manage.py migrate`)
9. Run server and check default site (`python manage.py runserver`)
10. Create superuser (`python manage.py createsuperuser`) and log in to admin area
11. Move database settings, allowed hosts and secret key from `base.py` to new file `local.py` in the same folder. Also any other settings that apply only to the local machine.
12. Create the git repository.

**Setting up POSTGRES backend**

With POSTGRES installed, from the command prompt, enter the POSTGRES command prompt:

```
psql -U username
```

- username is the db global admin login created during install

Enter the following commands to add a project database and a user with full rights on the project db:

```
CREATE DATABASE myproject;
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET timezone TO 'UTC';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
```

Type `\q` to exit the POSTGRES prompt.

In your virtual environment, install psycopg2:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Note, you may get a warning to install from an alternative source:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Create a blank database for the project. Set this up in the project `local.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'projectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Continue on to step 8 above.